# Which cabal packages aren't being used

Tags: haskell, cabal

If I crank up the warnings with GHC, it will warn me which imports aren't being used....

Is there a similar command to tell me which `build-depends` aren't being used in my `<project>.cabal` file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`packunused`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/packunused) is a *simple CLI tool allows to find out which of the packages listed as build-depends in a Cabal package description file are redundant*.

You have to build your project with `-ddump-minimal-imports` then run `packunused`:

```
cabal build --ghc-option=-ddump-minimal-imports
packunused
```

It will print a list of package dependencies that seem to be unused.

Comment: Looks promising, but I am struggling to get ```-ddump-minimal-imports``` working with stack....  I just put up another stackoverflow question to sort this out....  Will get back to this question when that is done.

Comment: To get it working with stack, I used ```stack build --ghc-options -ddump-minimal-imports```, then copied all the ```*.imports``` files to the cabal root, also a file called ```setup-config``` needed to be copied to ```dist/```.  All of these files were somewhere in ```.stack-work/``` (```find``` can be used to get the exact location).

Comment: @jamshidh Wow, that seems annoying. I've opened a feature request to work with stack [here](https://github.com/hvr/packunused/issues/18).